# The meaning of the word metal

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does the word metal mean here?

> Web Operations Weekly. A weekly newsletter on Web operations, infrastructure, performance, and tooling, from the browser down to the metal. 
>   https://github.com/vredniy/awesome-newsletters

I am not even sure how to make a research. I guess it's some kind of metaphor here.

Comment: "Down to the metal" is an idiom, meaning details down to the mechanical/electrical features of whatever contraption is being discussed.  Ie, in the above case there would presumably be details about the specific computers and their configurations that would be used in web operations.  (In a different context it might mean actually discussing circuits and computer chips.)

Comment: The expression "big iron" is related in the sense of server rooms and datacenters.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_iron

Comment: Very similar to the idiom, "bare metal", indicating that you are at the lowest level, closest to the problem. You can think of this metaphor:  stripping the paint on a car to the bare metal so that there are no foreign materials between the paint and the metal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computers are made of metal. *From the browser down to the metal* refers to the software and the hardware involved.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanx a lot

Answer (score 13):

From [a post on gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/643830-what-is-meant-by-coding-down-to-the-metal/#entry5066616):

> there was a time when "down to the metal" meant basically writing code
>   for the raw hardware (with no OS or device drivers involved), and
>   often with stuff written in a fair bit of assembler as well.

"Metal" refers to the physical hardware, trying to cut through the  driver or operating system levels, i.e. low level CPU, graphics programming, real-time embedded systems. Some call themselves "down-to-the-metal C++ programmers".

It might be related to the expression: "[pedal to the metal](http://www.answers.com/Q/The_origin_of_the_idiom_pedal_to_the_metal)", where (gas) pedal is fully depressed to the car floor, providing as much speed as possible, which is one of the purposes of "to the metal" programming. Additional shades are given in [Close To The Metal](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CloseToTheMetal), referring to code limited to some hardware or security issues..

Comment: Editing was indeed a good idea @curiousdannii

Comment: I don't think it is related to "pedal to the metal". There "metal" just meant the metal floor and it was a nice rhyme. "Metal" in that context doesn't really make a lot of sense in "to the metal" programming, (even with the "speed" connection, which is... another topic). "Metal" in "down to the metal" or "bare metal" just refers to the more "raw" lower level parts of a system (hardware and such like you say), it's not a synonym for a "floor" ("pedal to the metal" was not a metaphor like "down to the metal" is).

Comment: Per FOLDOC, the original phrase was "[bare metal](http://foldoc.org/bare%20metal)" and I think it's probably meant to make you think of machine parts that haven't been polished and painted yet.

Comment: @zwol Excellent FOLDOC reference, that made me discover the [bare-metal restore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare-metal_restore) acception, relating "bare metal" more precisely to hard drives.

Comment: @Jason C Possibly. Yet the  metaphor spreads with expressions like "pedal to bare metal", I have even seen a "bare-metal cloud"

Comment: @LaurentDuval "Pedal to bare metal" is a pun on the two unrelated phrases, used in literally a couple of articles and an obscure blog (Google the phrase). They're no more related than "pedal to the metal" is to "heavy metal". Can you clarify what you mean by "related"?